# Why Vercel function log does not show console.log?

Tags: next.js, vercel

I see this for server method `generatePostAnimation`

[image]

basically no log lines.

I have many console.log like this:

```js
console.log('Képek betöltve')
```

What do I miss?

https://vercel.com/support/articles/where-are-vercel-logs

Comment: This is a server console I pasted

Comment: Did you find a fix? I am having this issue too.

Comment: not really, but I figured out the primary issue I had in logic

Comment: Seems not to work for me as well...

Comment: Anyone with an answer?

Comment: @Taio Logs should appear within a few seconds. If they do not appear then most likely your code did log anything. Try adding more console logs earlier in your code to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a failed request — check the errors tab to see if there's something there. In any case, you're not seeing your console.log outputs since no request was registered (likely due to an error ^).